# Swift, how can I store a custom value for each dropped pin using MKPointAnnotation?

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkpointannotation

I want to be able to store a custom value for each dropped pin using `MKPointAnnotation`. Specifically, I want to store some id with each pin and retrieve at `calloutAccesoryControlTapped`.

Comment: Is this a question on how to persist data, or on how to do something with MapKit? What do you mean by "store a custom value"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to subclass MKPointAnnotation with a property to store this custom value (I named it tag)

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
class CustomPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
    var tag: Int!
}
```

Creating pins:

```
let annotation = CustomPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(latitude), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(longitude))
            annotation.title = [insert name]
            annotation.tag = [insert tag]
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

And in your mapView delegate's viewForAnnotation, after checking the dequeableAnnotation you do:

```
  if (annotation is CustomPointAnnotation) {
       pinView?.tag = (annotation as! CustomPointAnnotation).tag
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Minor edit to Marcos Griselli's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34258502/4978538). pinView needs to be cast to access the custom tag.

```
if (annotation is CustomPointAnnotation) {
    (pinView?.annotation as! CustomPointAnnotation).tag = (annotation as! CustomPointAnnotation).tag
}
```